# How can I use local json file to create a heat map (Bing Maps)?

Tags: javascript, geojson, heatmap, bing-maps

I'm trying to create a heatmap in Bing Maps from local data stored in a geoJson file, but I can't make it work... Oddly enough, there is absolutely no issue if that exact same file is online. Here is the script I'm using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function GetMap() {
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
        credentials: 'my_bing_maps_key_(not_forgotten)',
        zoom: 4
    });

    //Load the GeoJSON and HeatMap modules
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule(['Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', 'Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap'], function () {
        // Earthquake data in the past 30 days from usgs.gov
        Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl('data/all_month.geojson', function (shapes) {
            var heatMap = new Microsoft.Maps.HeatMapLayer(shapes, { radius: 5 });
            map.layers.insert(heatMap);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

With it, no heatmap layer appears. But when I simply replace it by this, everything is perfectly fine:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function GetMap() {
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
        credentials: 'my_bing_maps_key_(not_forgotten)',
        zoom: 4
    });

    //Load the GeoJSON and HeatMap modules
    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule(['Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', 'Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap'], function () {
        // Earthquake data in the past 30 days from usgs.gov
        Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.readFromUrl('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_month.geojson', function (shapes) {
            var heatMap = new Microsoft.Maps.HeatMapLayer(shapes, { radius: 5 });
            map.layers.insert(heatMap);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

I really don't understand what's the problem here.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both work for me when I try. Make sure that your local file is hosted in the same place as your webpage as your URL is a relative URL. i.e. If your webpage is http://mywebsite.com, the URL you provided expects the file to be at http://mywebsite.com/data/all+month.geojson.

IF you actually want to access a file on the users file system you have to use the HTML5 FileReader API as URL's can't access the users file system.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that this file was indeed on my file system when I tried to get it, hence the issue

Comment: Here is a code sample that uses the FileReader API to read GeoJSON files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750523.aspx